# Is it possible to send a file from Electron app to Express server by providing the path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, electron

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. User drags and drops a file into Electron
2. Electron uses a python script to convert it (child_process.exec)
3. Conversion creates a file in the same directory as the original file
4. Since I know the path (original file except different extension) the file gets uploaded onto the server, which stores it for future access.

I'm stuck at step 4. Whatever I do I can't seem to retrieve the converted file. This is what I've tried:

```
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append('model', createReadStream(filePath));

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'my/path',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${bodyFormData._boundary}`
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
    });
```

And this is what req looks like from express:

```
  body: { model: '[object Object]' },
  files: null,
```

I don't know if it's even possible. If it's not, I would appreciate any advice on other ways of achieving what I'm trying to do. I hope my explanation was enough, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself. Firstly, yes, it is possible to read files from the file system as long as you've got appropriate privileges.

All I did was to convert the file stream to blob before sending and it worked. I used [this awesome npm package called stream-to-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-blob) and it did the job perfectly.